# Is this an efficient way of replacing words in a string

Tags: java

I feel that there might be an more efficient way than searching the string three times looking for those matches to replace

```
str.replaceAll("_", " ").replaceFirst("^\\w*\\d{3}\\w*", "")
      .replaceAll("20\\d{2}", "")
```

The above is in a for loop that loops over a long string line by line

1. All _ (underscores)
2. A word that contains more than 3 numbers and is the first word in that line
3. Date 20** (2012,2013..)

Comment: Explaining which words you are searching for might help us out :p

Comment: I wouldn't care unless it has proved to be too slow. Don't preoptimize.

Comment: I don't see a much simpler way here. The three cases are very disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the same grammar but If you are able to join the three regular expression in only one like "**(_)|(^\w*\d{3}\w*)|(20\d{2})**" it can be more efficient.

The key is to try to found a single simple expression to do only one pass.

Comment: This is not quite equivalent, though. Only one word of the second kind should be replaced, not all.

Comment: I now that's not equivalent. I said "It's not exactly the same grammar but If you are able..."